# Export polygon from Raster by coordinates

Tags: python, gis, raster, gdal

I am trying to export polygon from raster.

I have 6 lat-lon coordinates.
If I type in the CMD the following command I can export but in a square form:

```
gdalwarp -te x_min y_min x_max y_max input.tif output.tif
```

Is there a way to export a polygon using coordinates ?

Thanks

Comment: What does `export` mean in this context? *Recognise*, *extract*? Write to some destination that part of the raster that's within a given polygon?

Comment: extract. Create a smaller image depending on the coordinates

Comment: Anyone know.. ?

Comment: The resulting raster will of course always be rectangular. Have you seen this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769531/gtiff-mask-with-shapefile-in-python-with-gdal-ogr-etc/23950892#23950892
These days the use of `subprocess` can be avoided by using `gdal.Warp`